# How will translate "谁让你" into English?

Tags: translation

How will translate "谁让你" into English? For example,

> 我不得不服从你的安排。 谁让你是我的老板呢？

Comment: It seems a bit weird. The more oft-heard phrase used is 谁叫你 instead.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow 誰讓你 and 誰叫你 sound both acceptable to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

谁让 expresses weak causality with a mood. Depending on the context and the tone, the mood can be humor, banter, sarcastic, helplessness, complaining or something else. Accordingly the translation can be "since", "after all", "only because", "God knows why", etc.

In your example, it seems the speaker is just grumbling or expressing helplessness in a cool mood. I would use "after all" in this one.

> I have to listen to you. You're my boss, after all.

Answer (score 2):

In most situation, 谁让你 can be translated into only because.
谁叫你 and 谁让你 are the same.

And 你 could be replaced by some other words like 我，他 etc

Answer (score 0):

The correct tranlation is "Who let you"