# How to say "用斜杠包围逗号" in english?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

Is this sentence "encircle the comma using slash" right?
Actually, I want to figure out this situation \,\
I doubt the word 'encircle' is not accurate.

Comment: This is not a Chinese Language and Usage question...

Comment: Where can I ask this question?I see a couple of questions like this.For example,http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-will-translate-%E8%B0%81%E8%AE%A9%E4%BD%A0-into-english/2251#2251               thanks

Comment: I might be wrong but IMO that question is really about the meaning of a specific Chinese idiom; this question is really about how to put something in English while the source language happened to be Chinese.

Comment: Please refer to [this meta Q/A](http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/a/241/798).

Comment: @liamxu - Hi Liam, I suggest you ask this question on the English StackExchange site http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @liamxu, this question can be asked perfectly in English since you have already made some effort to translate. However, the policy on translation definitely needs refinement to reduce such ambiguities as per your case and will post a request on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "[enclose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enclose)" would be a better word since "[encircle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encircle)" usually means to surround by forming a circle. Note that the character `\` is actually a [back slash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Characters), not a slash (`/`).

> "Enclose the comma with two back slashes."

Another alternative word is "[pad](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pad)":

> "Pad the comma with one back slash in front and one behind."

Or "[delimit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter)" if the purpose is to separate some text. But I doubt it is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the meaning you guessed is correct. Maybe it is best to translate  it as: Put the comma between slashes.