# 谁 as relative pronoun?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 至少今天她都不想再见到聂离了，**谁**让聂离骗了她。这是对聂离的惩罚！

Can 谁 here be translated as the relative pronoun who?

My literal translation would be:

> At least for today she, **who** has let Nieli to deceive her, doesn't want to see him.

However I searched in this same site and it says that there shouldn't exist a relative pronoun: [Are there relative pronouns in Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/are-there-relative-pronouns-in-chinese)

Comment: After thinking about it more, Maybe I found out the answer! Here the two sentences are actually not connected and it can be translated as: "who allowed him to deceive her? ". I thought that they were connected since there was a comma between the sentences and not a full stop. However if my hypothesis is right, there should be a question mark at the end.

Comment: Very interesting question, but your translation is wrong. 谁让 here means something like "because". When we ask "谁让somebody do something" as a rhetorical question, we mean "we all know no one sanctions that, but you/they still have done the wrong thing." And then when we put the 谁让 phrase as the supplement, we just express the cause for the bad consequence mentioned earlier in an ironic tone.

Comment: in this case either a question mark or a period works fine.

Comment: Related: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/how-will-translate-%E8%B0%81%E8%AE%A9%E4%BD%A0-into-english/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chinese does not have relative pronouns. In the case of the sentence that you gave, it would probably be best translated using "因为" (because):

至少今天她都不想再见到聂离了, 因为她让聂离骗了她 or in English:

At least for today, she doesn't want to see Nieli again, because she let Nieli deceive her.

EDIT:

In Chinese, instead of using relative clauses, particles like 的 are used instead. For example:

The man, who learns Chinese, is here.

学汉语**的**人在这儿。

In the above case, we use the fact that the person learns Chinese to describe said person, instead of having a relative clause.

Comment: "... Because Nieli deceived her." - No "she lets".

Comment: @Stan yup, thats what it says

Comment: That explanation is incorrect. It should be "至少今天她都不想再见到聂离了, 因为聂离骗了她" or in English "At least for today, she doesn't want to see Nieli again, because Nieli deceived her." Please read [the answer in NS.X's comment](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/2251/2816).

Comment: @Stan There is nothing wrong with including ”她让“ in my sentence. All it means is "she let." Sure, it doesn't technically need to be there, but that doesn't make it incorrect.

Comment: 1. "...因为她让聂离骗了她" is ill-formed, ungrammatical – such an error is called 句式杂糅. It should be either "...因为她让聂离骗了" or "...因为聂离骗了她". 2. It should **never** be translated to "she let", the character 让 in "...因为她让聂离骗了" is used to denote the passive voice, with the same function as 被.

Answer (score 1):

She never wanted to see Nie Qin again (at least not today).  That would fix him! Who told him (it was OK) to lie to her anyway?

This use of 誰叫/讓 is pretty common:
誰叫/讓你亂講話? 你挨打活該!
Who told you to open your big mouth? You deserved to get smacked.

Answer (score 1):

谁让/叫 + clause is a expression for reasoning, the clause is telling the reason for doing something, but the form is as a question